# UIView and intrinsicContentSize

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Does a UIView create an `intrinsicContentSize`?

I create a UIView contentView. I do not give it constraints size:

```
UIView *contentView = [UIView new];
[contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

I create another UIView subview01. I give it constraints size and add it to my contentView:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[imageView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[imageView(WIDTH)]"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:@{@"WIDTH" : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:imageSize.width]}
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imageView)]];

[imageView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[imageView(HEIGHT)]"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:@{@"HEIGHT" : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:imageSize.height]}
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imageView)]];


[contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

contentView does does not gain any size. I thought the `intrinsicContentSize` is suppose to calculate the size needed to show all subviews and resize itself? Like how a UILabel will resize to show all of its text?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, a UIView does not have an intrinsicContentSize. Buttons and labels do, since it's easy for the system to calculate that size based on the string and or image in them. For a UIView, you generally need 4 constraints to fully describe its position and size.

Comment: Or you can subclass the `UIView` and override `intrinsicContentSize` method.

Comment: but intrinsicContentSize is a UIView method that you would override

Comment: This is not correct. There are some cases where you may need to override a UIView's `intrinsicContentSize`. For instance, if a view contains a text view, you have to tell what the size of the view should be by overriding that method.

Comment: This is no longer accurate. Visual debugger on iOS 14 + Swift 5 is clearly showing a UIImageView trying to set its height and width based on the content size of the image it is displaying.

Answer (score 0):

While not a perfect solution, I did figure out a way to mimic `intrinsicContentSize`.

I set the container view's `NSLayoutAttributeRight` to the right most sub view's `NSLayoutAttributeRight` and do the same for `NSLayoutAttributeBottom` to the lowest sub view's `NSLayoutAttributeBottom`.

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:rightSubView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                         multiplier:1 constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:bottumSubView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1 constant:0]];
```